# How to get a character with diacritical mark from a string in php?

Tags: php

I'm writing a code that accepts the middle name of a person, convert it to upper then get its first character.
Example the user input the name "winston", then I'll get a capitalise "W".

I can use either of the 2 codes to get the first character of string and it works fine.

```
    mb_strtoupper(substr($name,0,1));
```

or

```
    mb_strtoupper($name[0]);
```

I'm using mb_strtoupper() so that it can convert a character with diacritics like ñ.

My problem is when the names first character have a diacritical mark.

```
Ñana
```

I'm testing a code,

```
    $name_1 = 'Ñana';
    echo strtoupper(substr($name_1,0,1));
    echo '<br>';
    echo strtoupper($name_1[0]);
```

The result

[image]

I tried to increase index of $name_1 and the parameter of substr().

```
    $name_1 = 'Ñana';
    echo strtoupper(substr($name_1,0,2));
    echo '<br>';
    echo strtoupper($name_1[1]);
```

The result

[image]

My code works if the the first character of the string don't have diacritics.

How should I handle it? Or How can I handle this kind of situation?

Comment: Try using `mb_substr()` instead of `substr()`: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-substr.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use `substr` for `UTF-8` encoded string, because you cut 1 byte out of a single multibyte character. Use [mb_substr](http://php.net/mb_substr) instead from the [Multibyte String Functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.mbstring.php):

```
echo mb_strtoupper(mb_substr($name_1, 0, 1));
```

Comment: mb_substr() is what I need. Didn't know that function exist!